# MVC Radio button selected one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have radio button as below for some reason even though the first one is checked, always the last one shows up checked on the form page. Why ? How can i fix this?

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsSatisFied, Satisfaction.Not, new { @checked = "true" }) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsSatisFied, Satisfaction.Maybe, new { @checked = "false" })  
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsSatisFied, Satisfaction.Yes, new { @checked = "false" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not set the `checked` attribute. `@checked = "true"` and `@checked = "false"` (and `checked` or `checked="checked"` or `checked="anything"`) all set the `checked` attribute. As the DOM is read, the first one is checked, then the second, and finally the last one is checked.

If the value of propery is `IsSatisFied` is `Satisfaction.Maybe` then the second radio button will be selected (that's how model binding works)

Comment: How does one dynamically add the checked attribute to the appropriate RadioButton? Assuming that the list of options is built dynamically.

Comment: @Kevin, You need to ask a new question withe the relevant details

Answer (score 0):

You're using malformed HTML. The proper way to mark something as checked would be

```
{ @checked = "checked" }
```

and don't include the checked attribute at all for the unchecked radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#radio-button-state-(type=radio)) says:

> When any of the following phenomena occur, **if the element's checkedness state is true after the occurrence, the checkedness state of all the other elements in the same radio button group must be set to false**:
>
> - **The element's checkedness state is set to true (for whatever reason).**
> - The element's name attribute is set, changed, or removed.
> - The element's form owner changes.

So as the HTML is parsed going down the page, if multiple radios are `checked` then the last one will always be selected. As such, you only want to set one checked attribute by setting `checked="checked"`:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(
    model => model.IsSatisFied, 
    Satisfaction.Not, 
    new { @checked = "checked" }) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsSatisFied, Satisfaction.Maybe)  
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsSatisFied, Satisfaction.Yes)
```